# Como converter este código de derivação em PHP para JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Estou com uma linda função de derivação escrita em PHP mas gostaria de passa-la para JavaScript e como ela tem muita "soma" eu não sei como transforma-la, alguém pode ajudar-me?

```
function derivate($key, $iv, $x) {
    $sha1_a = SHA1($iv + substr($key, $x, 32));
    $sha1_b = SHA1(substr($key, 32 + $x, 16) + $iv + substr($key, 48 + $x, 16));
    $sha1_c = SHA1(substr($key, 64 + $x, 32) + $iv);
    $sha1_d = SHA1($iv + substr($key, 96 + $x, 32));

    $A = substr($sha1_a, 0, 8) + substr($sha1_b, 8, 12) + substr($sha1_c, 4, 12);
    $B  = substr($sha1_a, 8, 12) + substr($sha1_b, 0, 8) + substr($sha1_c, 16, 4) + substr($sha1_d, 0, 8);

    return array(
        'A' => SHA1($A),
        'B' => SHA1($B)
    );
}
```

a função `SHA1` eu tenho funcionando normal

Comment: Editei o titulo para não soar como apenas um pedido, mas sim como algo útil para a comunidade.

Comment: Tem certeza que a pergunta não é: "como converter esse código para JS"? Pq basicamente se vc escrever essa função antes do teu código: `var substr = function(str, pos, len) { return str.substr(pos, len); };` teu código vai funcionar dentro da condição de vc ter uma lib pra *SHA1*

Comment: @GabrielGartz sim, era este o titulo mas foi remanejado por MODS

Comment: @Elaine opinião pessoal, acho o seu título melhor do que o alterado, colocou o código que eu escrevi, funcionou?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para converter este código de PHP para JavaScript não é preciso muito se você já tem a lib para *SHA1*, basta alterar a sintaxe e adicionar a seguinte função ao seu código:

```
function substr(str, pos, len) { 
    return str.substr(pos, len); 
};
```

No JavaScript o `substr` é um método do protótipo do objeto String, isso significa que ao invés de adicionar como primeiro parâmetro a string, você deve chamar diretamente da string. E este código é um "calço" para ficar parecido com o PHP.

E o Array você deverá utilizar um objeto literal no JavaScript, pois apesar de que Arrays permitem utilização de qualquer chave não numérica, não é a forma correta de utiliza-las.

```
return {
    'A': SHA1($A),
    'B': SHA1($B)
}
```

Você pode manter as variáveis com o caractere `$` assim como no PHP, porém no JavaScript ela não é necessária, mas como é um caracter unicode, e qualquer unicode pode ser usado para definir variável, este vai permitir. Mas não esqueça de adicionar o `var` antes das mesmas.

As operações aritméticas utilizam os mesmos caracteres em ambas linguagens.

O código final ficará:

```
function substr(str, pos, len) { 
    return str.substr(pos, len); 
};
function derivate($key, $iv, $x) {
    var $sha1_a = SHA1($iv + substr($key, $x, 32));
    var $sha1_b = SHA1(substr($key, 32 + $x, 16) + $iv + substr($key, 48 + $x, 16));
    var $sha1_c = SHA1(substr($key, 64 + $x, 32) + $iv);
    var $sha1_d = SHA1($iv + substr($key, 96 + $x, 32));

    var $A = substr($sha1_a, 0, 8) + substr($sha1_b, 8, 12) + substr($sha1_c, 4, 12);
    var $B  = substr($sha1_a, 8, 12) + substr($sha1_b, 0, 8) + substr($sha1_c, 16, 4) + substr($sha1_d, 0, 8);

    return {
        'A': SHA1($A),
        'B': SHA1($B)
    };
}
```

Se você estiver mais confortável com a notação orientada objeto de JavaScript pode remover o "calço" e escrever o código desta maneira:

```
function derivate($key, $iv, $x) {
    var $sha1_a = SHA1($iv + $key.substr($x, 32));
    var $sha1_b = SHA1($key.substr(32 + $x, 16) + $iv + $key.substr(48 + $x, 16));
    var $sha1_c = SHA1($key.substr(64 + $x, 32) + $iv);
    var $sha1_d = SHA1($iv + $key.substr(96 + $x, 32));

    var $A = $sha1_a.substr(0, 8) + $sha1_b.substr(8, 12) + $sha1_c.substr(4, 12);
    var $B  = $sha1_a.substr(8, 12) + $sha1_b.substr(0, 8) + $sha1_c.substr(16, 4) + $sha1_d.substr(0, 8);

    return {
        'A': SHA1($A),
        'B': SHA1($B)
    };
}
```

Um próximo passo seria remover o caractere `$` das variáveis, como mencionei anteriormente, funcionará com, mas não são necessários, pois efetivamente nada adicionam além de estética.